How do I indicate to a compiler data is aligned?
Given the code that wraps shared_ptr and std::span for some extra type safety:
template <size_t L>
class Vector {
 public:
  auto begin() { std::begin(data_); }
  auto end() { std::end(data_); }
  float* data() { return data_.data(); }
  float& operator[](size_t index) { return data_[index]; }
  size_t size() const { return L; }

 private:
  // Making sure it does not go away while vector exists
  std::shared_ptr<Store> store_;
  // Range in the Store where the vector data lives,
  // Address is 32 byte-aligned
  std::span<float, L> data_;
};

Say there are loops like the following (v1, v2 and v3 are vectors of the same length):
for (size_t i = 0; i < v1.size(); ++i) {
    v3[i] = v1[i] + v2[i];
}

or
auto it1 = v1.begin();
auto it2 = v2.begin();
auto it3 = v3.begin();
while (it1 != v1.end()) {
    *it3 = (*it1++) + (*it2++);
}

I would like to indicate to a compiler that vector data is aligned for AVX2 instructions, but I do not want to write SIMD code (as this will also be compiled for ARM and WebAssembly).
What is the best way to indicate the alignment?

See std::assume_aligned. Note that alignement does not matter much on x86-64 CPU nowadays (except maybe in critical cases in AVX-512).

@JérômeRichard Can I annotate return of begin() or operator[] with assume_aligned? Documentation is not clear in that regard. Sure, I can do pointers - but I don't trust my users

@Eugene: Is your comment asking whether it's meaningful to call std::assume_aligned in relevant Vector member functions, or whether there's some alternative to it that would be part of their declaration?

@DavisHerring my question is how to expose that hint to callers of the Vector API. E.g. how do I tell compiler on the caller site that Vector::begin() iterates over aligned data. I want the autovectorizer to have as much info as possible.

Per Jérôme Richard‘s comment, you can use std::assume_aligned for this purpose; just call it in the function returning a pointer to make it clear to the optimizer that it hasn’t changed since it was set:
auto begin() { 
  auto ret=std::begin(data_);
  std::assume_aligned<32>(&*ret);
  return ret;
}
float* data() {
  return std::assume_aligned<32>(data_.data());
}

The second version may optimize better than the first, since it gets to use the actual return value from std::assume_aligned; one could perhaps create a new std::span in begin to use it as well.

If std::assume_aligned works like GNU C __builtin_assume_aligned, you probably need to use the return value.  Like ret = __builtin_assume_aligned(ret, 32); or the C++20 equivalent.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/assume_aligned .  The example there says to use the return value instead of the original to assume aligned access.

(It's technically UB to even call it with a misaligned pointer, but I'd guess GCC and clang don't optimize based on that, because they have to define the behaviour of creating a misaligned __m128i* for Intel's clunky intrinsics API to work, e.g. _mm_loadu_si128( (__m128i*)&my_vec[i] ).  Is `reinterpret_cast`ing between hardware SIMD vector pointer and the corresponding type an undefined behavior?)

You can check whether it worked by compiling without AVX and looking for movdqu / paddd xmm,xmm vs. paddd xmm, [mem] (alignment required, unlike AVX vpaddd xmm, xmm, [mem]).  GCC and Clang will also use [v]movaps or [v]movdqa loads/stores when they have an alignment guarantee / promise, but MSVC and classic ICC will always use [v]movups / [v]movdqu which are slower on ancient CPUs (earlier than Nehalem / K10 for loads Bulldozer for stores.)
